# Как найти номер телефона в строке?

Tags: php

Есть строка типа

```
example text <a href="tel:1234567">123567</a> other tags
```

Как получить номер телефона? То есть то что после tel: и до ".

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: почему PHP? почему не  JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью регулярного выражения:

```php
$string = 'example text <a href="tel:1234567">123567</a> other tags';
preg_match_all('/<a href="tel:(\d+)">/', $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
// Выведет следующее:
// Array(
//     [0] => 1234567
// )
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать объект `DOMDocument` (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php) и работу с ним. Например получение элемента по тегу, у которого взять атрибут, у которого взять номер за счёт вспомогательных функций:

```
<?php
$myhtml = <<<EOF
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p><a href="tel:1234567">Hello World!</a></p>
        <p><a href="tel:95798846">Another Hello World!</a></p>
    </body>
</html>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($myhtml);

$tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach ($tags as $tag) {
    echo explode(':', $tag->getAttribute('href'))[1] . "\n";
}
```

output:

```
1234567
95798846
```

Comment: Хм, мне кажется автор явно указал, что работает со `строкой`, нет?

Comment: @ЕвгенийТихии в конце написано "other tags" . значит это DOM структура. Работу с html, с DOM правильно производить с помощью  соответствующих методов. А вот использование регулярок, как в предыдущем ответе [надо избегать](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/6138795)

Comment: @ЕвгенийТихии и да - весь html - может быть одной строкой ;-)

Comment: @СергейМишин, в вопросе есть хоть слово про то, что автор работает с кодом html-страницы? Нет, там конкретно написано "строка". Для поиска подстроки в строке используется функция `strpos()`, для поиска по регулярному выражению — `preg_match()`. И выбор автором принятого ответа явно дал понять, кто понял его вопрос, а кто нет.

Comment: @HakuKimura то, что автор выбрал какой-то ответ, не означает его корреткность и правильность. Просто так ему удобнее и в силу неопытности не смог понять какие нюасны и проблемы возникнут далее из-за такого подхода. Можно и микроскопом гвозди забивать. Но адекватность этого действия довольно сомнительна